# Changing Keyboard Increment to 0.5px or less in Illustrator CC 2017?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, alignment, pixel-grid

Has anyone experienced issues changing their 'Keyboard Increments' to below 1px (in AI preferences)? I haven't been able to change this to anything below 1px, 1mm, etc. I would like to set it to .5mm. I've turned 'align to pixel grid' and 'snap to pixel' off but still no luck. Really can't figure this one out, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you entering into the "Keyboard Increments" field?
 When you click OK and then go back in, is the value updated there as you would expect?

Comment: Because the pixel is the smallest unit of display and for crisp art you want it either on or off I wouldn't even try to divide a pixel.

Comment: Depending on your country settings it could be . (point) or , (comma) you have to enter. Illustrator accepts only one of the two.

Comment: @AAGD SOLVED!!! I have recently moved countries (AU to NL) and my laptop now responds to 0,5 instead of 0.5. Thank you so much it was driving me crazy.

Comment: @13ruce thank you, it was solved :) see above.

Comment: @Webster thank you, however I'm working on a vector illustration in a document set for print and moving in small increments is something I use a lot of for this type of work. But yes I agree having your document set to Align New Objects to Pixel Grid would be advisable for digital/web based projects.

Comment: @alicia Thanks, I'll add my comment as an answer, so you can mark the question as solved.

Comment: Moving to New Zealand should not make your computer swap the decimal point for a comma - since NZ uses the point symbol for decimals, not a comma.  Check your computer settings and make sure your location is actually set to New Zealand.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your country settings it could be . (point) or , (comma) you have to enter. Illustrator accepts only one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I can enter vallues below 1px in my Illustrator CC.

You can type excly what you want.

Unchek **Align New Objects to Pixel Grid** first.

Ex: type 0,1mm or 0,5px in the preferences panel.

In the picute below I typed: 0,5mm and it returned 0,05cm. That is my ruler units (cm).

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Hi LeoNas, I'm using the most recent AI version and 'align new objects to pixel grid' isn't under the transform panel any longer? In fact I can't seem to find it anywhere, and by default it's turned on so I can't move in smaller than 1px/mm increments. What version are you using in the  above screen shot? Thanks

Comment: Hello, @alicia . I am using CC2015.

Comment: Hi @LeoNas cool thanks, 'align new objects..' seems to have moved in the latest version. I believe it is now tucked away under the 'layout' view (top right hand corner). Anyway, my questions wasn't related to that in the end and is now solved. I was using a .(point) instead of a ,(comma) in the increments box.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Adobe CC 19... this setting is now found under the "view" tab. "Snap to Pixel" should be turned off.

[image]